# How do you query a Model by parent ID & created at date

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to find all the records that have a specific `channel_id`, and were made less than `1 day ago`. The query finds the records with the given `channel_id` but does not respect the date restriction. Instead, it returns records created at any date.

```
@discussions = Discussion.where('channel_id = ? and created_at > ?', current_user.subscription.pluck(:channel_id), 1.days.ago )
```

I expected to only get the Discussions that had relevant subscriptions `channel_id`, and were made less than `1 day ago`. But instead, this query ignores the created at restriction but returns the Discussions that had the corresponding subscriptions channel ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@discussions = Discussion.where("channel_id IN (?) AND DATE(created_at) >= ?", current_user.subscription.pluck(:channel_id), (Date.today - 1.day))
```

OR

```
@discussions = Discussion.where("channel_id IN (?) AND created_at >= ?", current_user.subscription.pluck(:channel_id), (Date.today - 1.day).end_of_day)
```

Or

```
Discussion.where("DATE(created_at) >= ?", (Date.today - 1.day))
            .where("channel_id IN (?)", current_user.subscription.pluck(:channel_id))
```

Comment: Still doesn't respect the date query. I used `@discussions = Discussion.where('channel_id = ? and created_at > ?', @channel.id, 1.days.ago )` in another controller and it worked fine

Comment: @scott.piligrim2018 Can you try the last query, breaking it into two where query, may work.

Comment: Yeah tested all 3 none of them work, very strange. I've even tried changing the >= to ==, and <= just to see if it would do anything. It doesn't

Comment: @scott.piligrim2018 Glad to know that, Feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@discussions = Discussion.where("channel_id = :channel AND created_at > :date", channel: current_user.subscription.pluck(:channel_id), date: Date.yesterday )
```

Comment: Although this code might (or might not) solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the problem is and **how** this code helps.